# Increase number of concurrent shells in PowerShell V2

Tags: powershell

I'd like to increase number of concurrent shells in PowerShell V2.I tried using the following command ,but I got no luck.The error I got is" Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help."
Can someone shine some light?

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxShellsPerUser="50"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just add to Keith's answer that you can find the command mentioned and much more in [Administrator’s Guide to
Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/news/archive/2010/03/03/administrator-s-guide-to-powershell-remoting.aspx). It's worth reading!

Comment: Have you checked http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1305 (eBook: Layman’s guide to PowerShell 2.0 remoting), just interested how it goes compared to the 'Administrators guide to ..'. I still haven't time to check this one by Ravikanth.

Answer (score 5):

From an elevated PowerShell prompt execute:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxShellsPerUser 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the single quotes.

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="50"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't activate winrm on my box, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(VS.85).aspx), the syntax is:

winrm set winrm/config @{MaxShellsPerUser="50"}